# What does this "will" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, modal-verbs

> Holden workers **will be hoping** for some direction on the company's future when company chairman Mike Devereux fronts the Productivity Commission in Melbourne today. ([ABC.net.au](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2013/s3908363.htm))

It seems like *be plus present participle* is to denote futurity. Then what does *will* imply? Is it for simple conjecture (epistemic), or is it adding some actualization meaning of the activity when *be hoping* can’t contain one?

Comment: In this exact context I don't really think it would make any difference if the sentence had started with *"Holden workers **are** hoping for..."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FumbleFingers is correct that, semantically, there's very little--if any--difference between *are hoping for* and *will be hoping for*.

It's not *be* itself that signals the future, it's **will be** plus the present participle that signals a future progressive action; but with the progressive tenses, there is generally already a future aspect involved (i.e. they are continuous and often project beyond the present).

So yes, in answer to your question, it's phrased as *will be hoping* because it points to a future action. And it's specifically *hoping* because of the progressive aspect.

There's a reason for the use of *will be hoping* rather than *are hoping*, and that is that the statement is to some degree conditional (i.e. it hinges on Mike Devereux heading the committee) and also, as you've noted, is speculative. The workers' feelings or *hopes* **will be** brought about **when**/after Mike Devereux assumes the lead of the Productivity Commission in other words.

It's speculation about exactly what feelings this change will bring about written by an outsider.

Revised as if the author is speaking for or is one of the workers:

> Holden workers are hoping for some direction on the company's future
>   as company chairman Mike Devereux fronts the Productivity Commission
>   in Melbourne today.

That's a much stronger statement.

Revised **entirely** in present tense:

> Holden workers **are hoping for** some direction on the company's
>   future **now that** company chairman Mike Devereux is fronting the
>   Productivity Commission in Melbourne.

Answer (score 3):

The "will" points to "when company chairman Mike Devereux fronts." At that future time, they will be hoping for a certain outcome from the commission meeting.